# EF Core 5 Nested Projection issue

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I am upgrading code from EF6 to EF core on .Net 5. The old code that used to work is shown as below but no longer works when use EF core. As the eroor message suggested add ToList(), I did that but still same error message. Any direction please ?

```
return _blContext.place1s.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Select(r => new placeDto
            {
                ID = r.place1ID,
                Citys = _blContext.Citys.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.place1ID == r.place1ID).Select(r2 => new BaseCityDto
                {
                    ID = r2.CityID
                }).OrderBy(o => o.ID)
            }).OrderBy(o => o.ID);
```

Getting the following error message

```
The query contains a projection 'r => DbSet<Citys>()'IOrderedQueryable<BaseCityDto>'. Collections in the final projection must be an 'IEnumerable<T>' type such as 'List<T>'. Consider using 'ToList' or some other mechanism to convert the 'IQueryable<T>' or 'IOrderedEnumerable<T>' into an 'IEnumerable<T>'.'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return _blContext.place1s.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Select(r => new placeDto
            {
                ID = r.place1ID,
                Citys = _blContext.Citys.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.place1ID == r.place1ID).Select(r2 => new BaseCityDto
                {
                    ID = r2.CityID
                }).OrderBy(o => o.ID)
            })
            .OrderBy(o => o.ID)
            .ToList();
```